# How does commit history work with git rebase --onto

Tags: git, git-branch, rebase, git-rebase

Im learning git and curious about how rebase --onto works

[image]

So in the picture, when `topic` is rebased onto `master`, you get the files that were created in `next`, but you dont get the log history of `next` right?

Example:

1. someone creates file.txt on the `next` branch, so now there's a commit saying file.txt was created
2. `topic` is created from the HEAD of `next`, and now `topic` also can see this commit where file.txt was created
3. `topic` is rebased onto `master` like in the bottom graph.

So now the `topic` branch cant see the commit where file.txt was created right? Since `topic` has a new base which cannot reach the `next` branch.
And file.txt is still in `topic` commit tree

Comment: You're showing a picture of _text_. Don't do that. Copy the text, paste it into the question, and format it as code.

Comment: Welcome. You can find information about [why it is better not to post images of code here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557), but in this case it isn't code that we'll be using to recreate; so not a big deal. In any case, [this Rebasing documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing) does a good job of explaining exactly what happens with history.

Comment: @theherk It is a big deal. A text reader cannot read the picture to someone who has trouble seeing.

Comment: Not saying it doesn't matter; it does, for the reason you point out and more. I happen to think sharing links explaining this is yet more important for new contributors. A modicum of courtesy is warranted, in lieu of curt instructions.

Comment: @theherk Neatly put.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct. The right way to refer to this is in terms of *reachability*. Let's say that the file was created and committed in the first `o` of `next` after the point where it branched from `master`. Then it is correct (and trivially obvious) to say that that commit is reachable from `topic` before the rebase but not reachable from `topic` after the rebase.

However, there's an important point to keep in mind, namely that in the rebased version of `topic`, there will (in the simplest case, where the creation of the file was all that happened) be *no such file*. Thus, though it is true that you can't "see" from the rebased `topic` how the file got created, there is no *need* to see that, because as far as the rebased `topic` is concerned, there is no file whose history would need to be explained.

And that, indeed, illustrates the entire point of what rebasing is. It doesn't merely copy the same commits wholesale. It *rewrites* the rebased commits in accordance with the new base. This is why rebasing is often said to "replay the changes" represented by the rebased commits. Rebasing doesn't merely somehow "glue" the commits onto a different place in the history in a simple-minded way. Rebasing creates entirely new commits! It *rewrites history*.

And by rewriting history, rebasing also in a very real sense *loses* history — just as your question implies! For that very reason, you should not blindly rebase when history is shared or valuable. For instance, those who rebase instead of merging, on the grounds that it makes the history look topologically "neater" are in my opinion throwing away historical information of potentially great value.

Comment: Not sure what's up with the DV here, but I was about to add an answer that explained what would happen if `topic` had modified `file.txt`. I think simply adding that hypothetical to your answer would improve this, to show both sides of with or without conflicts.

Comment: @TTT Yes, you'll notice I hedged by saying "in the simplest case where the creation of the file was all that happened". I didn't want to get into the more "interesting" situation where `topic` itself modified `file.txt`. I've explained elsewhere how the merge logic works for a rebased commit and why this makes conflicts particularly likely, and this is a very beginner question and was really about no more than reachability, so pedagogically I didn't want to extend the essay any further. Do feel free to add another answer going into detail about that if you want! Two heads are better than one.

Comment: That makes sense. I think we're good here. ;)